# Mysql syntax error on stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I run this code as a sql script from command line, and I get "you have an error in your SQL syntax" almost in all lines! Any ideas what is wrong here?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatemandate()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE _mandate_id BIGINT(20);
   DECLARE _has_succesful_payment tinyint(1);
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE cnt INT;
   DECLARE mandateCursor CURSOR FOR Select mandate_id, has_succesful_payment From mandates;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1; 
   OPEN mandateCursor;
   allmandates: LOOP
   Fetch mandateCursor INTO _mandate_id, _has_succesful_payment;
   IF done THEN LEAVE allmandates;
   END IF;
    Select COUNT(*) FROM payments WHERE mandate_id=_mandate_id AND status='OK' into cnt; 
            IF cnt>0 THEN
            SET _has_succesful_payment=1;
            END IF;

   END LOOP allmandates;
   CLOSE mandateCursor;
 END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `;` character is the default delimiter, so when MySQL sees the first `;` it thinks you are done.  When you create a sproc, you need to declare a different delimiter character, like so:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE updatemandate()
READS SQL DATA
 BEGIN
   DECLARE _mandate_id BIGINT(20);
   DECLARE _has_succesful_payment tinyint(1);
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE cnt INT;
   DECLARE mandateCursor CURSOR FOR Select mandate_id, has_succesful_payment From mandates;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1; 
   OPEN mandateCursor;
   allmandates: LOOP
   Fetch mandateCursor INTO _mandate_id, _has_succesful_payment;
   IF done THEN LEAVE allmandates;
   END IF;
    Select COUNT(*) FROM payment WHERE mandate_id=_mandate_id AND status='OK' into cnt; 
            IF cnt>0 THEN
            SET _has_succesful_payment=1;
            END IF;

   END LOOP allmandates;
   CLOSE mandateCursor;
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also a good idea to add the `READS SQL DATA` to the sproc definition [in case you need to support binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html).

Comment: thank you worked, but another interesting thing is; it works from command line as a sql script but give syntax errors when I copy paste the code to a Sql commander and try to execute from there, any idea?

Comment: @Spring - not sure, I've never use SQL commander - It does work fine from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Which error is produced? Which "Sql commander" are you using the command with?

Comment: Did a quick google search - looks like SQL Commander has it's own special syntax for using the delimiter command:  http://www.dbvis.com/doc/7.0/doc/ug/sqlCommander/sqlCommander.html#mozTocId437790

Comment: @Eric Petroelje amazing thanks! but I will leave it as it is, not to have problems in standart command line usage

Comment: @Eric Petroelje do you see any error in my algorithm, it works but does not set the column values in a loop as I want it to do, nothing changes.

Comment: @Spring - looks like all you are doing is updating the _has_succesful_payment variable.  You would need to issue an actual UPDATE statement in your loop to change the value in the table.

Comment: @Spring - in that case, you would also want to change the `READS SQL DATA` to `MODIFIES SQL DATA`

Comment: @Eric Petroelje tnx but could you tell me where to use update there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `delimiter //` before the `CREATE` statement and change the last line with `END //`?